# Can't understand how to compile go code in multiple files

Tags: go

OK, Go's major selling point is its ease of compilation and wonderful toolchain, but as a go newbie I'm really lost there and can't understand the documentation on that point.

I have a stack toy example within two files (one for the type definition and methods, called `stack.go`, one for the main program, called `main.go`), both are in my `GOPATH/src/stacker` directory.

1. How should each file be named ? Does it have any importance at all ? Is there at least a convention ? A mandatory naming ?
2. What should be the package name ? I understood they should use the same package name, but which one ? Is it `stacker` ?
3. In `main.go`, how should I use the `import` directive to import `stack.go` ?

I have tried many combinations, none working until now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

1. You can name the files however you like, just beware of special suffixes like `_test` and `_<arch>` (`_darwin`, `_unix`, etc.). Also note that files prefixed with `.` or `_` won't be compiled into the package!
2. It is recommended that you name the package like the folder the file is in, although it's possible (but confusing) to name a package differently in the declaration `package mypkg`
3. If `stack.go` is in the same folder/package as `main.go`, you don't need to import. Everything delcared in `stack.go` is already available in `main.go`, because it is in the same package.

If `stacker` should compile into an executable, you should use `package main`.

Comment: You should mention that, if `stacker` should compile into an executable instead of being an import package, it be should be `package main`.

Comment: @ANisus and Erik, thanks for your answers. Works perfectly now and I'm starting to get the overall idea.